# Create a pop-up class

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, object-oriented

I'm new to OOP, so I tried to learn from tutorials how to create a class in JavaScript/jQuery. But tutorials don't give you feedback from experienced coders. Is the approach to create a pop-up OK (see below)? I know it works (it's tested), but is it prone to errors or does it have redundancies?

```
var Popup = function (){
    /// PROPERTIES
    var new_id="div"+Date.now();
    var defaults = {
        id: new_id,
        container: "body",
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        text: "<div> created with \"id\" = "+new_id,
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        position: "absolute",
        bgcolor: "red"
    };
    this.settings=defaults;
    /// METHODS
    this.create=function (options){
        $.extend(this.settings,options);
        var html= "<div id=\""+
            this.settings.id+"\">"+
                this.settings.text+
                "</div>";
        $(this.settings.container).append(html);
        this.update();
    };
    this.update=function (options) {
        $.extend(this.settings,options);
        $("#"+this.settings.id).css({
            "height":this.settings.height+"px",
            "width":this.settings.width+"px",
            "position":this.settings.position,
            "top":this.settings.y,
            "left":this.settings.x,
            "background-color":this.settings.bgcolor
        });
    };
};

/* Popup use:

var pop=new Popup(); // new popup is declared
pop.create({bgcolor:"green"}); // popup appears green instead of read
pop.update({bgcolor:"blue"}); // popup changes to blue

*/
```

(I know there are a tons of Popup plugins that I could use, but that's irrelevant for my learning goals)

For example, I've realized that this line will cause problems:

```
this.settings=defaults;
```

because when "settings" are changed, "defaults" change too (!). Thus, the better alternative is:

```
this.settings=$.extend(defaults);
```

or a JavaScript "clone" function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/4902724).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code looks good
The one improvement is do not overwrite the initial settings, instead extend from defaults and the options provided. Use **$.extend** for this

```
 popup.settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

Also store the reference of **this** into a variable so that it will be used inside event handlers and anonymous callbacks.

```
var Popup = function() {
    var popup = this,
        new_id = "div" + Date.now(),
        defaults = {
            id: new_id,
            container: "body",
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            text: "<div> created with \"id\" = " + new_id,
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            position: "absolute",
            bgcolor: "red"
        };

    popup.create = function(options) {
        popup.settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var html = "<div id=\"" +
            popup.settings.id + "\">" +
            popup.settings.text +
            "</div>";
        $(popup.settings.container).append(html);
        popup.update();
    };

    popup.update = function(options) {
        popup.settings = $.extend(defaults, options);
        $("#" + popup.settings.id).css({
            "height": popup.settings.height + "px",
            "width": popup.settings.width + "px",
            "position": popup.settings.position,
            "top": popup.settings.y,
            "left": popup.settings.x,
            "background-color": popup.settings.bgcolor
        });
    };
};



var pop = new Popup(); // new popup is declared

pop.create({
    bgcolor: "green"
}); // popup appears green instead of read

pop.update({
    bgcolor: "blue"
}); // popup changes to blue
```